# dual boot reinstall problems

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, updates

My Ubuntu installation crashed during updating and will now not boot fully. I have tried reinstalling as from a previous answer on here suggested but the option to wipe my original Ubuntu installation is not there.

I don't want to wipe my windows install, just reinstall the Ubuntu partition. I assume this can this be done from the something else option - but there are lots of options when I go to 'edit partition' which I'm not sure about. I'd think it should be an 'ext4 journaling file system' and format the partition but thought I would check before messing with settings I don't understand. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can this question's title be [edit]ed to not resemble hundreds of other questions in this community? If this question is unique, how can the title be changed to reflect its uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**,choose something else option and select the previously installed ubuntu partition then format it to ext4 journaling system.And then install your newer Ubuntu on that same ext4 partition.

Before doing the above,don't forget to backup  important datas from the previously installed Ubuntu partition.